# single partition & no initramfs linux boot gets kernel panic

Tags: linux, kernel, boot, panic, syslinux

- compiled a kernel using gentoo specifications for Thinkpad T430
- mounted empty ext4 hard drive and created boot/ directory on it, moved bzImage and System.map inside
- Installed extlinux to it with "extlinux --install [mounted directory]/boot"
- placed syslinux.cfg inside with the following config:

  ```
  DEFAULT linux
    SAY Now booting the kernel from EXTLINUX...
  LABEL linux
    KERNEL /boot/bzImage
    APPEND root=/dev/sdb rw init=/bin/bash
  ```
- Created bin/ folder in mounted hard drive, placed bash binary inside

At this point i'm able to boot the kernel to the point where it has to run init, however it panics:

```
---[ Kernel Panic - not syncing: Requested init /bin/bash failed (error -2). ]---
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

4chan solved my question in 10 minutes, i didn't have the libc.so libraries